# Selenium confirm box

Tags: javascript, selenium

I'm using Selenium for auto testing.

Though the reference manual says it doesn't support JavaScript.
Would like to know if any alternative is there for passing confirm dialog box?

My script is failing when trying to click "OK" on confirm box.

Failing at this line

```
    assert /^Quantity Unavailable\. Do you want to continue[\s\S][\s\S]$/ =~ @selenium.get_confirmation

Gives error "OR: There were no confirmations"
```

Can any one have a solution?

Thanks in advance,
Srinath.

Comment: That should be clicking on the OK button for you implicitly.

p.s. what manual says Selenium doesn't support JavaScript because that is just WRONG!!!!

Comment: Hi, Could you please tell how to handle this. if it clicks implicitly . thanks